# What is happening with Polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

I have an Interface [a] and a Implementer class [b]. [b] have its own methods apart of the implemented ones.

```
//-----------
public interface a
{
void functionA();
}
//-----------

public class b:a
{
void functionA(){}
void functionB(){}

}
//------------
```

In project X inside the solution. When I code: [project is a class library]

```
a test = new b();
test.functionB(); //It Works
```

In another project with a references to the library [Console application]

```
a test = new b();
test.functionB(); //Error CS1061 --> a doesn't have a method called function b
```

Sorry but names are  in spanish. Interface: pastebin.com/Unm5Adkd, Implementer: pastebin.com/wmikck9H, Program: Console app: pastebin.com/Yus91hQL... Thanks everyone for your help. :P

Comment: Neither of them should work; `a` does not have a method called `functionB`.

Comment: The code sample which works is in error.  The code you provided should only compile the first sample if there was an extension method.  The code you provided in itself won't ever compile that sample.  Did you omit some code?

Comment: Are you declaring the first example using the "var" keyword? I think you need to post a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: -1 till the first sample is in compilable state (or at least does not produce obvious "a does not have functionB")

Comment: I just posted the pastebin of the 3 clases  look at the original post. I dont compile of course. But if I implement an interface I dont have to just have the interface methods I being a class can have more methods. The polymorphism work great, but outside the project is a mess. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are asking why you are getting the CS1061 error.

It's simple. In your console application even though you instantiate an object of type 'b' ("new b()") you appear to assign it to a variable referring to something that is an 'a'. The interface 'a' according to your sample does indeed not contain a method called 'functionB()'.

You have two options in this case.

Option one is adding method 'functionB()' to the interface definition as well:

```
public interface a {
   void functionA(){}
   void functionB(){}
}
```

Option two is making sure that variable 'a' in your console application is of type 'b':

```
b a = new b();
a.functionB();
```

On a side note I would suggest to stick with generally accepted naming guidelines, e.g. starting with uppercase letters for names of classes and methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lets say now Father and Child. Although Base doesnt have that method the object was builded as Child. The code: Base a = new Child(); is working inside the current project(the class library) also the method is displayed in intellisense autocomplete. The problem is outside that project in the Console Apllication. I dont get it cause reference is set already.

Comment: I think you need to provide more context, e.g. more source code of both  the library and the console applications. Otherwise there are too may options for what is going wrong.

Comment: The project is for educational Purpose so i can post the source code, but Can I upload it on IDK pastebin and put the link here?

Comment: You can do that but I cannot guarantee any specific response time.

Comment: Oh shhhhht... Now i get it. When I say: Father a = new Child(), i can only use father defined methods. Thats a kind of protection, I just do the test in java with father, child class. Also tested with Object and Child. My bad guys.